# javascript clientWidth: why is this returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I'm trying to understand why this is returning undefined.

```
function showMarquee(marquee_string) {
    $('#text-helper').html(marquee_string);
    var test = document.getElementById("text-helper").innerHTML;
    var width = (test.clientWidth); //why isn't this line working?
    alert(width);  //this returns undefined
}
showMarquee('Silver Linings Playbook');
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="currentwatchtext" id="currentwatchtext">
    <div id="marquee-screen"></div> 
    <div id="text-helper"></div>    
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#text-helper{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Any input on the matter is appreciated.

Comment: You're setting `var test` to the `innerHTML` of text-helper

Answer (score 4):

The value of an `.innerHTML` property is a **string**, and strings don't have a "clientWidth" property.

Comment: Ok but even if I use `var test = $('#text-helper').html();` I still get `undefined`.

Comment: @DnfD that's because the return value from the jQuery `.html()` method is *also* a string.

Comment: Right right, makes sense. Only other option is `.val();` then? Which is also returning undefined.

Comment: @DnfD `clientWidth` is a property of an element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth . Get the **element**, not its **innerHTML** (string)...then access the `clientWidth` property. Or, as the next comment more properly suggests, use jQuery methods to get what you need.

Comment: *What are you trying to do?*  If you want to get the width of an element, jQuery has `.width()`, `.innerWidth()`, and `.outerWidth()`, and you apply those to the wrapped element itself, not its value or contents.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is return the width of the element. I've tried `width();` `.innerWidth();` and `.outerWidth();` which all return 0.

Comment: @DnfD [here is a working jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6Brrf/)

Comment: Appreciate the fiddle and that is exactly what I have in my code...wish I was joking. Still returning 0 though. Using latest version of Firefox, no errors in console.

Comment: @DnfD Are you *sure* it's the same? Are you sure you've got `"#text-helper"` in the jQuery call, and not just `"text-helper"`?

Comment: Yep, 100% sure. Copied and pasted the fiddle to make sure also. Still 0.

Comment: @DnfD And you're sure your page is importing jQuery, and that you're running your code in a "ready" or "load" handler?

Comment: Yep, jQuery used in multiple other places in this js file and working correctly.

Comment: @DnfD well all I can do is wish you good luck in finding what's wrong with your code, as the approach in the fiddle clearly does work. Keep in mind that a bad jQuery selector (one that matches nothing on the page) is *not* an error; it just won't do anything. Check the `.length` of the jQuery object you're getting back before calling `.width()`.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answers and criticisms. This should be so easy and is becoming quite frustrating. And yep, tried `.length` and was successful. Just no dice with `.width()`.

Comment: @DnfD Are you sure the element is visible and loaded at that time? I don't think `.width()` will report the correct value if it's hidden